# error WinSock.h has already been included Boost Windows Qt

Tags: c++, qt, boost

I am using boost lib on Qt creator to develop an application, my platform is Windows8 MSVC2013 64.

I have two class on each I am using boost headers,

Now I need to use this class and when I include these class header from another source file I am getting the error

```
error WinSock.h has already been included
```

In my fist class I added boost header like

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_time.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
```

and in second class I used the header on same way

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread_time.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/sync/interprocess_semaphore.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/placeholders.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
```

I already found the answer here [Boost::asio winsock and winsock 2 compatibility issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750344/boostasio-winsock-and-winsock-2-compatibility-issue) but still I am having the issue.

**Edit:**
My second class internally using the first class header, does that be the cause like multiple time including the boost headers?

I have surrounded the boost header includes with

```
#ifndef class_obj__1
#define class_obj__1
//boost headers
//boost headers  
#endif
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks
Haris

Comment: Are you getting the error on the first class or the second class?

Comment: The error message is like `C:\boost\boost_1_58_0\boost\asio\detail\socket_types.hpp:24: error: C1189: #error :  WinSock.h has already been included`

Comment: Have you tried putting the include of `<iostream>` and  `<fstream>` after all the `boost` headers for the second class?

Comment: Yes I tried that too...

Comment: I'm assuming the problem comes from the second class. Try moving `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` first.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion, I tried it but no luck, actually my source file contain large files, right now trying with only boost part on new project.

Comment: if you are using visual studio enable `show includes`, you will find the culprits.

Comment: No I am developing  with Qt creator.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Move the `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` to g++ command line argument list as `-DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN`. This helped me.
One more thing helped me is reordering `#include` directives to put `boost` includes before all others.